# How to get the nth value from the last/end part of the file?

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to ask how to get the nth value (e.g. the 7th) from the last part of a file in bash.

Example:

```
   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

With the above line, I would like to get only the 7th value (which is "brown").

Comment: dcc, _nothing_ in the question or comments from the OP gives any indication that they meant string. They specifically mentioned _file_ so, unless you can get confirmation from OP, you should not change the nature of the question. Reverting. And, while I have no problem with you adding tags to my answer text, you made more substantive changes (such as referring to sed commands as flags, which they're plainly not) that rendered the answer less useful, so I've reverted my answer as well, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the seventh-last word fairly easily.

One approach is to get the file as a one-word-per-line stream, grab the last seven lines of that stream, then grab the first line of those seven.

For example, with the input file `infile`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog.
```

you can use the following command sequence:

```
pax> sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//;s/  */\n/g' qq.in | tail -7 | head -1
brown
```

The `sed` has three commands to it (separated by semicolons):

- remove leading spaces from each line `s/^ *//`;
- remove trailing spaces from each line `s/ *$/`; and
- turn all remaining groups of spaces into a single line separator (note that there are *two* spaces before the asterisk in this part) `s/  */\n/g`.

The first two commands are to ensure that spaces at the start or end of a line do not cause extraneous newlines.

The `tail` then gets the last seven lines and the `head` gets the first of those seven (i.e., the seventh last line).

Comment: the command works great!Unfortunately, answer can no longer be accepted because of time limit.

Comment: @meme, there's a _minimum_ time you have to wait before accepting, to ensure you get a decent cross-section of answers you can evaluate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer - I think it's 15 minutes but I tend to wait days before accepting answers to my questions.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
S="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
echo $S | awk '{print $(NF-6)}'
```

Comment: May be cannot resemble exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of an array/word splitting to avoid external tools:

```
$ read -a temp <<< "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
$ echo "${temp[${#temp[@]}-7]}"
brown
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `tac` + `awk` :

```
$ cat infile 
Query String: The quick brown 
fox jumps over 
the lazy dog.

$ tac infile |awk -v nword=7 '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--){if(++a==nword){print $i;end}}}'
brown
```

`tac`: will reverse the line order.

`awk`: for loop to itinerate fields from last to first, a counter to stop at number 7.